# What steps I can execute to ensure my clientlibs for author do not load on the publish view in AEM?

Tags: aem

We are setting up a fresh AEM 6.2 project and the application will make use of some author specific client libs and some publish specific clientlibs;
We want to ensure that the author specific client libs do not unnecessarily load up on the AEM publish instances. Please guide us as to how we can achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

Hi Adobe document for the clientlibs creation process is below.

https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/develop/the-basics/clientlibs.html

consider below points while design phase that will lead to the best practices implementation.

1. multiple components with their own JavaScript and CSS files
2. global JavaScript and CSS files
3. apps folder is not available on the publish instance
4. CSS resources have to go in the `<head>`, JavaScript resources    at the end of the page
5. Resources need to be minified
6. Some resources    need to be merged

http://blogs.adobe.com/experiencedelivers/experience-management/clientlibs-explained-example/